# Can I make a multiplayer Android Game using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a multiplayer android game, where the clients connect together via a web server.

My question is: Is it possible to make this kind of games using Android Studio with other libraries like LibGDX and Java sockets?

Comment: Android Studio is just an IDE ( i.e. a very suped up text editor). As you could make a multiplayer game in notepad you can also make it in Android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course! You can make multiplayer game with Android Studio, you can utilize Firebase too if you don't have any online server to manage peer connection.
If you prefer using Java Socket Library, you will need to manage the server too or just play it locally like how ShareIt works..
Here are some reference for making a game with Android Studio:
1. [LibGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki)
2. [LibGDX Text Tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx)
3. [LibGDX Video Tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Video-Tutorial-Series.aspx)
4. [Example game built with Android Studio](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/gallery.html)

Library for managing peer connection:
1. [Firebase Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)
2. [Socket.io](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) (Socket Library)

If you want to connect with other peer via internet with Socket.io, you will need to implement NodeJS Server or PHP Socket Server..

Comment: Please avoid answering off topic questions.